# Setting the text size of a tab with ViewPagerIndicator doesn't work

Tags: android, font-size, android-tabs, viewpagerindicator

In my project I have a `ViewPager` that is not linked to the action bar and I'm having problems with setting the font size of the text for the tabs. I'm using ViewPagerIndicator (v2.4.1) in combination with ActionBarSherlock (v4.3.1).

The layout I'm using is:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/artistIndicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/artistPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp" />
```

This is within a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. The layout works as expected and I see no problems with the interaction between the `ScrollView` and my `ViewPager`.

Styling of the `ViewPager` and tabs is done with the following XML:

```
<style name="ArtistIndicatorTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/ArtistInfoTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>

<style name="ArtistInfoTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ArtistInfoTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="ArtistInfoTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="@style/TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tab_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/activity_position_artistinfo_font_size</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

The background of the tabs is handled by the following XMLs to create a actual tab-style look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" />
</selector>
```

And the two shape XMLs for selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/text_inverted" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/text_inverted" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and unselected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/text_inverted" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip" android:right="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/text_important" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The current font size is set by the following dimension:

```
<dimen name="activity_position_artistinfo_font_size">15dp</dimen>
```

Any indication on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you try changing it from 15dp to 22sp ? just for trial?

Comment: I've tried using various settings like 10dp and 20sp. Just tried 22sp and still I get the same font size.

Comment: Did you try setting the text size directly inside the TabPageIndicator element in xml?